Movie where people need to find a device of a philosopher from ancient Rome or Greece
I’m looking for a movie I watched a while ago. From what I remember there’s a guy and a girl who together with an older man have to find the tomb, and a device of a philosopher (or something like that) from ancient Rome or Greece. When they find the device they realize it is a time machine and they accidentally time travel back into ancient Rome/Greece where there is an invasion ongoing (a lot of ships sailing toward land to invade). They meet the philosopher there and the older man stays in this time while the 2 (guy and girl) decide to go back to their time.

Can you be more specific about "a while ago"? Your description sounds very much like the fifth installment in the Indiana Jones series, Indiana Jones and the Dial of Destiny, but that only came out last year.

How long is a while ago? This sounds like Indiana Jones and the Dial of Destiny, quite recemt.

Absolutely worth watching the films in sequence to get the connections and what's going on with the  girl.

Also, Phoebe Waller-Bridge was ~36 years old at the time of filming, so very much not a "girl", but I still think it might be Dial of Destiny. It would really help if you responded to the requests for clarification.
